# how to download a project which is available in Google svn

Tags: svn, google-code

I want to download [this](https://project4example3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/) project in to my eclipse indigo. How to do this.

I tried to go to this link and I am able to see the project but it is quite difficult to download the same.

how to get it downloaded using eclipse indigo.

Comment: Hi shx2 Thanks for the edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install SVN plugin for eclipse and do checkout or just

`svn checkout http://project4example3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ project4example3-read-only`

in command line like Google code suggests.

Comment: Hi Ivan Borisov, Thanks for the post, will try this and accept your answer if this works.

Comment: Good Ivan, i have practically up voted for all your answers so for, good job done. :)

Comment: Thanks. I was pleased to help.